# adding an object in an Array in javascript trough code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, object

My teacher made an array in my javascript file that i am not allowed to change.
I am supposed to add new objects to it trough code without touching that array.

This is what my array looks like:

```
const words = [{
    dutch: "vork",
    english: "Fork",
    dutchDescription: "Iets waarmee je eet dat doorgaans vier tanden heeft.",
    englishDescription: "Something you eat with that usually has four tines.",
    isknown: false
  },
  {
    dutch: "mes",
    english: "knife",
    dutchDescription: "Bestek dat snijdt.",
    englishDescription: "Cutlery that cuts.",
    isknown: false
  },
  {
    dutch: "lepel",
    english: "spoon",
    dutchDescription: "Bestek waarmee je soep eet.",
    englishDescription: "Cutlery you use to eat soup.",
    isknown: false
  }
];
```

I tried to make it like this:

```
function addCustomWord(object) {
  const words2 = [{
    dutch: "testDutch",
    english: "testEnglish",
    dutchDescription: "dutchDiscriptionTest",
    englishDescription: "englishDiscriptionTest",
    isknown: false
  }]
  words.push(words2);
}
```

That clearly doesn't work and i am having a hard time trying to find anything that actualy works. I have been trying very different solutions for hours and i can't find anything that works.
Could someone help me with my problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: The question seems to be quite unclear, you could try to give the original question your teacher asked, and include all relevant code inside the OP (not just images of code)

Comment: You're pushing another array in array with your object not the single object, you have to remove the square brackets and push only the object.

Comment: You can't add new objects to an array you're not allowed to change. You can, however, produce a new array with the original content, plus the object you want to add. Is that what your teacher wants?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the square brackets from words2 because words two is the element you need to add